# Reading data from a text file to an array and sending it using shared memory in c

Tags: c, arrays, file

This is my first time asking directly for help.  I am trying to read data from a text file, then send it using shared memory to other process. Shared memory is working as intended, the problem is that array is being filled only with the first 15 characters and then it sends that 15 characters over and over again until it reaches EOF. I would like the array to refill itself with new characters from a file, just don't know how. Here is a portion of my code.

EDIT: I figured out that for some reason (probably my mistake) the offset wasn't moving forward after filling the array, so i manually set offset to move. It solved the problem that only first 15 characters of a file were read, however it isn't ideal. While reading a file it is sometimes missing some letters and sometimes the order of the words is switched.
Could someone explain to me why does it happend and what can i do about this?

EDIT2: I think i solved the problem myself, below there is edited code which seems to be reading just fine most of the time. If anyone can think of better implementation don't hesitate to post it. For now, my solutions seems "good enough"

EDIT3: I'm still missing some letters, but i increased shared memory space, like you said so it's actually not a problem now to share longer words.

```
int z;
int i;
char text[256];
while(1) {
  FILE* fp = fopen("/path/to/my/file", "r");
  if (fp) {  
     fseek(fp, z, SEEK_SET);
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",text)!=EOF) {

      s = shm;
        for (int i = 0; i < SHM_SIZE; i++) { //this loop loads characters from array to a shared memory
        *s++ = text[i];
         z++;
      }
    }
  fclose(fp); }
}
```

Comment: Please, what kind of formatting is this?

Comment: i dunno is it better now?

Comment: No! it is worse.

Comment: now it's perfect

Comment: Why are you using such a tiny buffer? `fscanf` will gladly blow right over the end of that array. You may be looking for [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).

Comment: It's just a part of a project, next proces has to display the text file in 15 character blocks, that's why I keep it so small

Comment: About fread, i will try it later and will let you know if it works. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: `FILE* fp = fopen("/`..)` at some time in the future, you will have to close this file. And get out of the loop.

Comment: What is the data in your file?

Comment: it's a text file with a random characters. 
Fread gives me the same result as fscanf 
you are right, i willl close the file

Comment: Ok i updated my code and encoutered different problem.

Comment: posted my solution

Comment: hello, can anyone help me? I'm out of ideas why at first it's missing some characters and later is working as intended?

Comment: You said you moved resetting the pointer out of the loop, but I don't see that in your code. You're using `fseek` with an uninitialized variable the first time, and I don't see why you're seeking at all. You're assigning from the array you read to SHM_SIZE that we can't see, when you should probably only be assigning what you actually read, like `strlen(text)`. You say you're missing data but we can only see half of what's going on. The problem could very well be in whatever is consuming the data but you haven't shown that.

Answer (score 0):

You reinitialize `s = shm;` during each iteration of the loop, which means you write each line to the start of shared memory.  If you want to fill all of shared memory with the file, initialize it once, before the loop.

This is a school assignment, but in the real world, you might simply use a shared memory mapping for the file.

Comment: i moved it out of the loop and it didn't change a thing